# Puppeteer click on elements from generated modal

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, puppeteer

I have been looking on a lot of posts from here, but I could not find my answer.
My problem is next: I have a button that popup a generated modal (we use some npm package). The problem is that whatever I do, I can't get elements from that modal.

```
async function transferToAPerson(page) {
const transferSidebar = "#sidebar-menu\\ sidebar-menu-rewritten > li:nth-child(6) > div > button";
const phoneInput = "#phoneInput > input[type=tel]";
const amountInput = "#__BVID__25___BV_modal_body_ > div > div.row.mt-20 > div:nth-child(1) > input";
const send = "#__BVID__25___BV_modal_body_ > div > button";
const confirm = "#__BVID__27___BV_modal_body_ > div > h5";
const done = "#__BVID__27___BV_modal_body_ > div > button";



await page.$(transferSidebar);
await submit(page, transferSidebar);
await page.waitFor(1000);

// const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.on('targetcreated', target => x(target.frame())));
// console.log(newPagePromise);

await page.$(phoneInput);
await inputType(page, phoneInput, "070060000");
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.$(amountInput);
```

@submit is a personal function that basically click on an element but it also verifies some things

Any idea how can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: What are the symptoms of "can't get elements from that modal"? Any error in terminal or they return `undefined`? Actually the `await page.$(selector)` lines you are using makes less sense to me. Aren't you mean `await page.waitForSelector(selector)`?

Comment: I read on some topic that the await page.$(selector) is almost the same as page.waitForSelector(selector). When I try to obtain elements from modal i get the following error: `Error: No node found for selector: #__BVID__25___BV_modal_body_ > div > div.row.mt-20 > div:nth-child(1) > input`

Comment: Actually they have pretty different purpose, I suggest to try to replace the hardcoded `page.waitFor(ms)` and `page.$(selector)` lines to `await page.waitForSelector(selector)`. `page.$` is only a `document.querySelector(selector)` inside the `page` context, it won't wait for the element to be rendered. Your error msg states puppeteer hasn't found your element inside the DOM. It can mean 2 things: you are using the wrong selector, or the element is not yet present in the DOM the time you want to use it.

Comment: At this point, I have used your recommendation with `page.waitForSelector(selector)` but I still get the almost same error message (now he waits but still could not found that selector): `TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#__BVID__25___BV_modal_body_ > div > div.row.mt-20 > div:nth-child(1) > input" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded` P.S: Sorry for late reply.

Comment: No problem. If you inspect the elements in devtools: isn't the modal a new frame (frameset or iframe etc)?

Comment: It doesn't look like a frame, this modal is triggered via vuex at @click on some button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217076/discussion-between-vader-and-thedavidbarton).